# Equivalent definitions of a lower semi-continuous weight

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $A$ be a C*-algebra and $\phi: A_+ \to [0,\infty]$ be a weight on $A$ (see for example Pedersen's book *$C^*$-algebras and their automorphism groups*, section 5).

Assume the following : If $A_+ \ni x_i \uparrow x$ then $\phi(x_i) \uparrow \phi(x)$.

Then the following seems to be true:

**Claim:** $\phi^{-1}([0,\alpha])$  is closed, for any $\alpha \in [0,\infty)$, i.e. $\phi$ is lower semi-continuous.

If we now take a say sequence $(x_n)$ in $A_+$ with $x_n \to x$ and $\phi(x_n) \leq \alpha$  we want to show that $\phi(x) \leq \alpha$.

The problem is then to find an increaing sequence $(y_n)$ in $A_+$ which still converges to $x$ and such that $\phi(y_n) \leq \alpha$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a direct argument (of course I could be wrong about it).

The way I know is as follows:

- A normal weight is an infinite sum of positive normal functionals. So, via an approximation argument, the question is reduced to functionals.
- For a positive functional, normality is equivalent to wot/sot continuity on bounded sets (note that you are allowed to take sequences, by the wot-compactness of the unit ball). This is done for instance in Theorem 7.1.12 in Kadison-Ringrose.

**Edit:** a proof, for a weight $\phi$, of the equivalence between

- $\phi$ is normal
- $\phi$ is wot-lower-semicontinuous

was given by Uffe Haagerup, J. Functional Analysis 19 (1975), 302–317. The proof also takes most of Chapter 1, Section 1, in Stratila's *Modular Theory in Operator Algebras*.

Comment: Okay, so probably one just has that lower semi-continuous weights preserve suprema.